# Custom JS not loading in apostrophe but CSS is

Tags: zurb-foundation, apostrophe-cms

I'm having trouble getting my custom js to load when adding it to my themes module in apostrophe. Custom CSS is following the same setup and not encountering an error. I've followed documentation and previous SO solutions on theme setup.

Current setup:

```html
my-theme
  - public/
     - css/
         - foundation/
             - foundation.css
             - app.css (custom overide for foundation)
     - js/
         - foundation/
             - vendor/
               - foundation.js
               - jquery.js
               - what-input.js
             - app.js
   - index.js
```

In index.js I reference the stylesheet (app.css) and js (app.js which loads foundation.js)

What should I be doing so that foundation.js runs properly and doesn't get blocked? I do believe it's getting pushed with self.pushAsset

Functionality I'm trying to recreate:
https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/topbar-center-logo.html

UPDATE:
I've discovered that the issue is with `$(document).foundation()` which lives in app.js and is needed to load foundation properly. Any suggestions on how I should be calling foundation?

Comment: Can you share the `my-theme/index.js` configuration code your currently using (including calls to `pushAsset`)

Comment: Hey Stuart, thanks for your help. Here's the code; what-input loads well and app.js only has `$(document).foundation()`. I moved everything to apostrophe-assets instead of my-theme but follows same setup.

`module.exports = {
    stylesheets: [
      {
        name: 'app'
      }
    ],
    jQuery: 3,
    construct: function(self, options) {
      // modules
      self.scripts.push({ name: 'modules/foundation', when: 'always' });
      self.scripts.push({ name: 'modules/what-input', when: 'always' });
      self.scripts.push({ name: 'modules/app', when: 'always' });
    }
  };`

Comment: and these scripts are located in the project level apostrophe-assets, like this `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/modules/foundation.js` ? Can you throw some console logs in there and see if they are making it to the browser? Maybe you are trying to leverage them before they're loaded

Comment: Yes, right there. I tried recreating the problem though with a fresh apostrophe-samples and couldn't. It works fine there so the issue appears to be with a conflict with my other code. Still investigating exactly what part of my code is causing the issue but safe to say it isn't apostrophe given I couldn't replicate. And thanks for the console logs tip, very helpful!